# Why is clang throwing these warnings?

Tags: c

```
user@thisbox Tests % make ./null_a_ptr 
cc     null_a_ptr.c   -o null_a_ptr
null_a_ptr.c:17:20: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') from 'int *' [-Wint-conversion]
                myarray[i].pthis = &p;
                                 ^ ~~
null_a_ptr.c:22:24: warning: comparison between pointer and integer ('size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'void *') [-Wpointer-integer-compare]
                if (myarray[i].pthis != NULL) {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~
null_a_ptr.c:30:20: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') from 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]
                myarray[i].pthis = NULL;
                                 ^ ~~~~
null_a_ptr.c:35:24: warning: comparison between pointer and integer ('size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'void *') [-Wpointer-integer-compare]
                if (myarray[i].pthis != NULL) {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~
4 warnings generated.
user@thisbox Tests % ./null_a_ptr     
sizeof(&p) is 8
myarray[0].pthis is initially not NULL
myarray[1].pthis is initially not NULL
myarray[0].pthis is finally NULL
myarray[1].pthis is finally NULL
user@thisbox Tests
```

In reality, mystruct describes a calloc-ed array (address & element count). sizeof(element) is known elsewhere.
There may be up to 20 such calloc-ed arrays (real-world #define MAGIC 20), but some will be empty/emptied ...hence the desire to set a NULL pointer.

My code appears to work, but **QUESTIONS**:

These warnings clutter up compile reports: How to get rid of?

Is is portable to assume size_t pthis always initialises to NULL? (it does with Clang on M1 Mac)

Code needs to compile & run on M1 Mac and Win(whatever is current).
M1 Mac compiler throwing these warnings is Clang.

Thanks for any ideas, Chris

Code to replicate:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAGIC 2

struct mystruct {
    size_t pthis;
    int thiscnt;
};
struct mystruct myarray[MAGIC];

int main(void) {
    int p = 1234; // just to get a pointer
    printf("sizeof(&p) is %lu\n", sizeof(&p));
    for (int i = 0; i < MAGIC; i++) {
        myarray[i].pthis = &p;                // <<<<< WARNING
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MAGIC; i++) {
        printf("myarray[%d].pthis is initially ", i);
        if (myarray[i].pthis != NULL) {       // <<<<< WARNING
            puts("not NULL");
        }
        else {
            puts("NULL");
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MAGIC; i++) {
        myarray[i].pthis = NULL;              // <<<<< WARNING
        myarray[i].thiscnt = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MAGIC; i++) {
        printf("myarray[%d].pthis is finally ", i);
        if (myarray[i].pthis != NULL) {.      // <<<<< WARNING
            puts("not NULL");   
        }
        else {
            puts("NULL");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is usually a bug to treat pointers as integers and vice versa.  The whole point of having a language with a type system is to help catch bugs like that.  The compiler is giving you a warning so you can make sure your code is OK.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose my question should have been "how do I declare pthis in my structure" ...seems like my size_t is the correct size, but wrong. Working on  it...

Comment: `size_t` is an integer type, not a pointer.  Replace that with `int *` as suggested  by dbush.  Literally just replace `size_t` with `int *`.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Thanks, got it, loud & clear! ...trying now. Chris

Comment: ...worked! Thanks for helping a newbie. Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a warning because you're attempting to assign a pointer value to an integer type.  Don't do that.

Instead, change the `pthis` member to have type `int *` to match what you're assigning to it.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose my question should have been "how do I declare pthis in my structure" ...seems like my size_t is the correct size, but otherwise wrong type. Working on understanding int *

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store an address into a non-pointer type variable, use `uintptr_t` type.

That said, use `%zu` to print the result of `sizeof` operator, as it's of type `size_t`.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose my question should have been "how do I declare pthis in my structure" ...seems like my size_t is the correct size, but wrong type. Looking at int * and your uintptr_t